# Creating a Serial Port in code in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, serial-port

I am trying to create a serial port in VB.net using code only. Because I am creating a class library I cannot use the built-in component. I have tried instantiating a new SeialPort() object, but that does not seem to be enough. I'm sure there is something simple I am missing and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

P.S. I should add that the problem I am having at this time is getting the code to handle the datareceived event. Other than that it might be working, but I can't tell because of that problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the events make sure you declare your serialPort object using the 'withevents'.  The below example will allow you to connect to a serial port, and will raise an event with the received string.

```
Imports System.Threading

Imports System.IO

Imports System.Text

Imports System.IO.Ports


Public Class clsBarcodeScanner

Public Event ScanDataRecieved(ByVal data As String)
WithEvents comPort As SerialPort

Public Sub Connect()
    Try
        comPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM5", 9600)
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub Disconnect()

    If comPort IsNot Nothing AndAlso comPort.IsOpen Then
        comPort.Close()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub comPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles comPort.DataReceived
    Dim str As String = ""
    If e.EventType = SerialData.Chars Then
        Do
            Dim bytecount As Integer = comPort.BytesToRead

            If bytecount = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Dim byteBuffer(bytecount) As Byte


            comPort.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bytecount)
            str = str & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, 1)

        Loop
    End If

    RaiseEvent ScanDataRecieved(str)

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130709121945/http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx) to be quite good.

The code i wrote from it is:

```
port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(name, 4800, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One);
port.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
port.Open();

void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    buffer = port.ReadLine();
    // process line
}
```

Sorry it's C# but...

The only issue I have with it is if the port is dropped while it's open, the app seems to fail on exit.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help, especially the answer about instantiating a class using the WithEvents keyword.

I found a really great article that explains how to create a manager class for the serial port. It also discusses sending Binary as well as Hex data to the serial port. It was quite helpful.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic37361.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have used the SerialPort .Net class in a past project and I worked fine.  You really don't need anything else.  Check the hardware setting in the control panel and make sure you instantiate the class with the same parameters.