# VB or Visual C++ for a PHP developer

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++

I need to build an application outside of my normal comfort zone (web/PHP/JavaScript).  Should I use C++/C# or Visual Basic to create my application?  I think that the syntax of C# is more like PHP, so that is why I'm thinking to go with C.  But also, I have heard that VB is much more straightforward for building a semi-simple application.

Here are just a few specifics of this app:
Needs to be a windows application that is compatible with a touch screen.
Needs to be able to connect to a remote MySQL database.
Needs to be able to take a snapshot of a live video feed and store in JPG.
Needs to be able to use a serial port interface to read a weight scale.

Also, will the express versions of the VB or C# work for what I need?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should try them out. c# looks more like php and with the ide vb and c# are almost equal (c# is even better)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice between VB.net and C# is fairly simple. They are just different syntax for the exact same things. I would choose C# as its closer to PHP and javascript, but you are completely free to choose.

I would throw visual C++ out. If you have no experience with C++, its almost never the right choice for .net programming if C# will accomplish what you need.

> will the express versions of the VB or C# work for what I need?

To my understanding, the only different between the express and paid editions is the ability to do a release build, and some other features that make it easier to work as a team. If you are solo and don't need tons of speed, you should be ok. If that changes or you find express isn't enough, the upgrade is realllly simple to do. :D

Comment: You're definitely wrong about the release builds.. they are available in the Visual Studio Express editions.

Comment: The difference between Express and other editions are simply lack of development features (things that are handy to have). The Express editions are fully capable of producing the same binary images.

Answer (score 2):

Consider going with either C# or Visual Basic. They're well suited for line-of-business applications. C++ might be a bit of a learning curve. Both VB and C# are very close in their feature-set. The express editions will suit you find. It doesn't sound like paid SKUs won't provide anything that you would be wanting.

As for the application, consider:

- the [MySQL connector for ADO.NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). It will allow you to use `MySqlCommand`, `MySqlConnection` and an assortment of datareader classes.
- this sample project for [DirectX Video Stream and Frame Capture with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/DirXVidStrm.aspx). The author has provided some source code you might find useful in getting started.
- for your serial port code, consider that VB has the `My.Computer.Ports` where you can hook into the serial you'll need. Check out the [handful of answers on this question about reading serial ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329865) to get a feel for the code involved in both VB and C#.

Answer (score 1):

C# and VB.Net are very similar, just use the one that feels easiest. If you've never done C++ before I'd say that either C# or VB.Net would be much easier to get going with.

You should be able to do everything you need in either of them, but you might need to use some PInvoke to use some Windows APIs if you need to do something that's not supported by the .Net framework. I can't think of anything that you need to do that wouldn't be supported by the Express versions, though I'd suggest that if you're writing anything more than tiny project, getting the Pro version so that you can use Addins etc might be nice.

Edit: Here's another question about what's lacking in VS 2008 Express, will be quite similar in 2010 I'd say: [What is "missing" in the Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions)