# I need help converting my driver user interface code

Tags: .net, c, driver

I have a custom driver I have written.

Here is the source code to communicate to the driver in C:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*********************************************************
* Main Function Entry
*
*********************************************************/
int _cdecl main(void)
{
HANDLE hFile;
DWORD dwReturn;

hFile = CreateFile("\\\\.\\Example", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

if(hFile)
{
WriteFile(hFile, "Hello from user mode!", sizeof("Hello from user mode!"), &dwReturn, NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);
}

return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to do this in .NET preferaly in VB.NET.

Does anyone know how to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to use P/Invoke to [OpenFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.OpenFile), [WriteFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.WriteFile) and [CloseHandle](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CloseHandle).

Answer (score 1):

You may find using the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class in the .net framework is easier.  Check out the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329865/creating-a-serial-port-in-code-in-vb-net).

Comment: This really isn't relevant to the question.